# how can I know the code of HTML is making a new line?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

**My code:**

```
<div id="box">
    <p>
        123
    </p>
    <p>
        abc
    </p>
</div>
<script>
    var html = document.getElementById("box").innerHTML;
    for (var i = 0, len = html.length; i < len; i++) {
        var word = html.charAt(i)
        alert("_" + word + "_" + i)  //Attention!!      when the "i" == 0
        if (i == 0) {
            alert(word==" ")        // it is false.....
        }
    }
</script>
```

Using API : "chatAt" ,how to write I could know the code of HTML is changing new lines.....(word == what????)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that you're looking for?

```
var html = document.getElementById("box").innerHTML;
for (var i = 0, len = html.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (html[i] === "\n") {
        // new line
    }
}
```